# API image popup finding the correct src path

Tags: javascript

I have an API image gallery using Unsplash [https://codepen.io/aaron_1986/pen/WNybEmZ]; when I click to enlarge an image - the path of the src is missing. Moreover, I cannot understand how to enter the correct src path to enlarge the image.

```js
//API CODE:

let imageElement = document.querySelector('.image-box');
function loadImg(url) {
    let col = url.value;
    imageElement.innerHTML='';
    for(let i=1; i < 10; i++) {
        let rand = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8) * i
        let url = `<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?${col}%20${rand}">`;  
        imageElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', url);
    }    
}

//POPUP CODE:

const images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.image-box')];

// popup

const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn');
const largeImage = document.querySelector('.large-image');


images.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        updateImage(i);
        popup.classList.toggle('active');
    })
})

const updateImage = (i) => {
    let path = ``;
    largeImage.src = path;
}

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    popup.classList.toggle('active');
})
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <span class="close-btn"></span>
  <img src="" class="large-image" alt="">
</div>

<div class="container images">
  <div class="images section">
 <div class="image-box">
  <!-- images src code -->
 </div> <!-- image box -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically your issue is the following:

Whenever you click on an image in order to enlarge it, you toggle the `active` class on your `div.popup` element which makes visible.

```html
<div class="popup">
  <span class="close-btn"></span>
  <img src="" class="large-image" alt="">
</div>
```

However you never set the src of the `img` element inside your popup.

You could try adding an id to the `img` tag inside your popup and setting the image src dynamically.

```html
<div class="popup">
  <span class="close-btn"></span>
  <img id="preview" src="" class="large-image" alt="">
</div>
```

```js
images.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        // get the `src` of the clicked image and pass it to the `openPreview` function
        const imageSource = event.target.src
        openPreview(i, imageSource);
        popup.classList.toggle('active');
    })
})

const openPreview = (i, src) => {
    // let path = ``;
    largeImage.src = src;
}
```

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/lo1c/pen/bGKNmGr